# Wordpress multisite on different subfolders can't install plugin via network

Tags: plugins, multisite, network-admin

I have configured a multisite in order to use different subfolder for every site.
I have started installing plugins on the network and while the installation works on the main site (https://mywebsite.com/stage/site1 ), nothing happens on the other site (https://mywebsite.com/stage/site2).
It happen with theme installation too. It seems the installation are completely independent even if multisite is activated and the correct domain is defined.

What can be the reason of this behavior?

The following code has been used for wp-config.php

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mywebsite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/stage/site1/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

while this has been used for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /stage/site1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The website structure is:

https://mywebsite.com/stage/site1 (main website)

https://mywebsite.com/stage/site2 (secondary website)

Hope someone can help me to figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Multisite installs already support subfolder/subdirectories for sites on the network without making additional special changes to HTAccess or `wp-config.php`

Comment: Hello @TomJNowell and thank you for the quick reply! 
I didn't make a particular configuration, I have only copied and pasted the .htaccess and wp-config.php snippets as provided by Wordpress.
I would like to install and manage plugins for both sites (so if I activate a plugin via network, it should be installed on every site, as it should be).
Do I need to modify the configuration?

Comment: Normally, you have a root site, e.g. `/ABC` and all sites are relative to that URL, your main site does not have to be your root site, it could just as easily be a site at `/stage` that redirects to a second or third. This is also assuming you've added the above in the correct location like any other `wp-config.php` adjustment. What I'm seeing though means that `/stage/site2` can never work, especially with that HTAccess that explicitly references `/stage/site1`. `/stage/site1/site2` might work with how you have set it up though

Comment: The /stage/ folder contains many other websites. I need a /stage/site1 to be the root site, which is need to be in network with /stage/site2. I would like to specify that /stage/site2 has a previous wp installation.

Comment: then what you're suggesting is not feasible as long as there are multiple installs, multisite lets you put multiple sites in 1 singular install of WordPress. If `/stage/site2` already contains a copy of WordPress in that folder then that needs to be resolved first. You can't just overwrite it by adding a blog to a multisite in another folder and giving it that URL. This all sounds very messy, you should clean things up first. _Why_ does `stage/site1` need to be the root site? It sounds like you have requirements that are incompatible with each other

Comment: @TomJNowell first of all thank you for the explanation. 
I have developed the first website on /stage/site1 so I supposed converting it in a multisite was enough. What do you suggest? Do I need to delete completely the second wp installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146256/discussion-between-stefano-and-tom-j-nowell).